# How to disable kernel_lockdown (MSR) without BIOS or console access

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, secure-boot

I have a laptop with a damaged screen. I use it by connecting a screen via HDMI. I'm running some cryto mining software that requires MSR access to run efficiently.

I cannot access the BIOS to disable secure boot.

I cannot access the console to use mokutil.

Help!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I guess there's no difference between your legitimate problem and someone attempting to alter a system it doesn't own: if it's possible for your case, it becomes possible for the other case, which means there's a security problem in the way the feature is implemented. Won't the boot display to HDMI in addition to the (broken) screen (thus allowing proper physical access for mokutil)?

Comment: My HDMI screen only displays once I'm prompted to enter the decryption password for the hard drive. I'm running Debian 12 and using "encrypt entire drive using LVM". I'm assuming, although I don't know for certain (since I've never actually seen it) that the mokutil menu choices come before that point.

Comment: And -no- I never see the BIOS setup screen on the HDMI monitor.